# Bit arithmetic in C

Tags: c, binary

Say we have 11101111 stored in the `address` address, how would I add the first 4 bits to the last 4 bits?

My prof showed us we can do this `(*address)/16 + (*address)%16` but I don't understand why it works. Can someone explain where the division and modulo with 16 come from?

Comment: 2^4 = 16 - dividing by 16 is equivalent to shifting off the last four bits.

Comment: Compute the binary results of *a/16 and *a%16.

Comment: You should learn a bit more about binary and numerical bases in general

Comment: What do you propose to do with any carry bit?

Comment: I learned about division and remainder at elementary school.

Comment: @nneonneo: That's wrong for signed integers!

Comment: As commented the `/16` shifts the upper 4 bits to the lower 4 bit positions. The `%16` is the division remainder, which isolated the lower 4 bits. It could as well be done with `(*address)/16 + ((*address)&15)` which also masks off the lower 4 bits. You should be working with `unsigned` 8-bit type, because a larger type will leave more significant bits after the division.

Comment: @WeatherVane how does the modulo get the lower 4 bits?

Comment: Because the remainder of *any* positive number divided by 16 is in the range 0..15. This is basic arithmetic.

Comment: @VanGo: Please read a C book. The modulus and division operators are explained in every beginner's book. We are no tutoring site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@VanGo, See to perform operation on bits, you have to learn bitwise operator first.

I am explaining your problem here.

11101111 (is in binary form) and is equivalent to 239 (in decimal). 
Now you have to add 1110 in 1111. In order to get these two pair of 4 bits from 11101111, you have to perform bitwise operation on 11101111.

To get higher 4 bits, shift 11101111 four times from left to right.

*address >> 4  :- is equal to *address/16

internally compiler convert *address>>4 into (*address)/(2 pow 4).

To get lower 4 bits, either perform (*address)&0x0f or (*address)%16. Both operation will clear all bits except lower 4 bits.

```
    printf(".....%d\n",(((*address)>>4) + ((*address)&0x0f)));
```

hope it helps you.